# How to use trim() text LPWSTR type in WIN32 API

Tags: c, string, winapi, trim

I have: `LPWSTR str="  Nguyen Phong Sac         "`
How to trim str.
It means: `str="Nguyen Phong Sac"`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: For what its worth, the only line of "code" in this question isn't correct. Its a wide string. Also, the literal is read-only (or at least it should be) yet is being assigned to a read/write pointer var (of the wrong type).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Be aware that this function has not been thouroughly tested, it's just to get the idea.

```
void Trim(TCHAR *buffer)
{
  int i = 0;

  while (buffer[i++] == ' ' && buffer[i] != 0) 
  {
  }

  int first = i - 1 ;

  i = lstrlen(buffer)  ;

  while (buffer[--i] == ' ' && i > 0) 
  {
  }

  int last = i + 1 ;

  int j = 0 ;
  for (i = first; i <= last - first; i++)
    buffer[j++] = buffer[i] ;

  buffer[j] = 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Using isspace would be better, in my view

Comment: It is not better, these ancient C runtime functions don't deal with Unicode well.  At least use iswspace(), but do consider what kind of glyphs in Unicode are considered space characters by your CRT.  There are a lot of them.